# Dell ubuntu Repositories authorisation Key

Tags: dell, repository

I've just purchased a Dell Precision 7520 with Ubuntu 16.04. I needed to reinstall the Ubuntu version with partitions for the root and home and now I want to install the Dell Repositories which this machine had on it originally. They were:

```
http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ exnial-dell-crane-kbl public
http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ exnial-dell-crane-kbl public (source Code)
http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ exnial-dell public
http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ exnial-dell public (source Code)
```

How can I do this in the Software & Updates window (Other Software Tab)? I need to install some open software drivers which were in the Additional Drivers Tab (when I bought it).

Answer (score 5):

> **Note:** This answer assumes you're running on Ubuntu 16.04, codename `xenial`. If this is not the case, please edit your post to reflect the version of Ubuntu you are planning to install.

It's much easier to just add these to a `sources.list.d` file. Run this command:

```
cat << 'EOL' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/dell-repos.list
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ xenial-dell public
deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ xenial-dell-crane-kbl public
deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ xenial-dell public
deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ xenial-dell-crane-kbl public
EOL
```

When you run this, copy and paste ***all*** of it. Do not run it line-by-line.

After you're done with the above, run this command:

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys F9FDA6BED73CDC22
```

Finally, run this command to update your package cache:

```
sudo apt update
```

Your Dell repos will now be added to your system, and you will be able to install packages freely.

Comment: This also works in 18.04 if you replace xenial with bionic although dell don't seem to have any available packages in their repos. The dell-crane-kbl repo no longer exists though.

Comment: `dell-crane-kbl` is available (http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/xenial-dell-crane-kbl/), you might be interested in adding more dell repos for bionic, however I am not sure about difference between `kyloren-mlk-13-15`, `bucky` and all others

Comment: what do the cryptic names mean?