# Installing remaining drivers for Dell Precision 7520

Tags: drivers, dell

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 on Dell Precision 7520. I reinstalled the factory Ubuntu 16.04 installation in order to get separate partitions for root and home. However I found out after doing that the Additional Drivers on my re-installation had only one item: the processor microcode firmware for Intel CPU's not the same as that on my factory installation which were  [five drivers](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BydO76o1EqLkRTBCTTAxUUxaWk0). I got help from [askubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/968383/dell-ubuntu-repositories-authorisation-key) to install some Dell repositories which were on the original installation hoping that would solve my drivers problem. It helped, it added another [two drivers](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BydO76o1EqLkMGJYNExITVhGX2M) but not all of them. I'm missing the remaining two (ie: 1. compat-iwiwifi-core19-intel8265 driver in DKMS format. From compat-iwiwifi-core19-intel8265-dkms (open source) and 2. bluetooth firmware for Intel8260 from bt-intel8260-firmware (open source). Do you know how I could get them working?

Comment: The ones you find "missing" are no longer needed. As the times goes that tends to happen because hardware support is added to the kernel (original 16.04 came with 4.4 whereas 16.04.3  runs on 4.10).

Comment: Thanks sounds Good.  I noticed in the original installation the Open Source driver was used for the Processor microcode firmware for Intel microcode. But the one I have installed is using the proprietor driver. How can I change to the open sourced version?

Comment: CPU microcodes (firmware) are always proprietary, regardless of how it shows up in Additional Drivers. It's recommended to use it as it provides improved process handling by the CPU. Just select the one shown in Additional Drivers.