# sudo apt-get update failed

Tags: apt, updates, dell, update-manager

the output of sudo apt-get update command are below:

```
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mozilla-daily/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Get:11 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease [102 kB]    
Hit:12 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease        
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/brackets/ubuntu xenial InRelease   
Err:14 http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates xenial-dell InRelease         
  Could not connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.89.6), connection timed out
Fetched 306 kB in 2min 0s (2,551 B/s)                      
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/xenial-dell/InRelease  Could not connect to dell.archive.canonical.com:80 (91.189.89.6), connection timed out
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: It's there and it works. Try again.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced the same issue, and looking for another mirror solves this issue

from /etc/apt/sources.list edit this part

`http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/dists/xenial-dell/InRelease`

Replace "dell.archive.canonical.com" with another mirror with the same purpose or packages you needed it to if it has.

Comment: It would be useful to others if you included a working mirror.

Comment: Hi Mark, Thanks for pointing it out

After searching I've found this link hopefully it will be helpful:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/968383/dell-ubuntu-repositories-authorisation-key/968391